# ctree R not displaying levels

Tags: r, ctree

Having trouble using ctree in R, sometimes it does not display any levels at all, here is an example below.

Can anyone explain why. thanks

```
library("party")

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
    colnames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c")

    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("Y","M","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("Y","F","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("Y","M","Y")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("Y","F","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","F","Y")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","M","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","M","Y")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","M","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","F","N")
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("N","F","N")

    df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
    df$b <- as.factor(df$b)
    df$c <- as.factor(df$c)

    TMDT<-ctree(a ~ b + c,data=df)
    plot(TMDT,type="simple")
```

Comment: Is `ctree` from the `partykit` package?

Comment: party, added it above

Comment: it looks like your tree has only one node (the outcome has 2 levels ``Y`` and ``N`` that are displayed with ``type = "extended"`` )